# Calculate group mean with the same grouping factors several times

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have genetic data. It is quite big, about 17 000 genetic markers (SNPs) and 700 individuals. These SNPs can be assigned to a founder. 
Now I want to calculate the average probability per 'founder segment'. A segment is defined as a part of the chromosome that is assigned to one founder uninterrupted.

In the example below I would have 3 segments.
In the end I want to know the average probability over all SNPs within a segment.

```
Chromosome SNP Founder Probability
 1       1     7      0.6 
 1       2     7      0.5 
 1       3     7      0.7 
 1       4     2      0.5 
 1       5     2      0.8 
 1       6     7      0.6 
 1       7     7      0.5
```

I can group easily with `dplyr`, but I don't want the first segment of founder 7 together with the other segment with founder 7.

So what I want:

```
Chromosome SNP Founder Probability Average
 1       1     7      0.6        0.6
 1       2     7      0.5        0.6
 1       3     7      0.7        0.6
 1       4     2      0.5        0.65
 1       5     2      0.8        0.65
 1       6     7      0.6        0.55
 1       7     7      0.5        0.55
```

How can I calculate group mean I when have the same grouping factors several times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can compare the adjacent elements of 'Founder' to create a grouping variable along with 'Chromosome', and then get the `mean` of 'Probability'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Chromosome, grp1 =  cumsum(Founder!=lag(Founder, default = Founder[n()]))) %>%
  mutate(Average = mean(Probability))
# Chromosome   SNP Founder Probability  grp1 Average
#       <int> <int>   <int>       <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
#1          1     1       7         0.6     0    0.60
#2          1     2       7         0.5     0    0.60
#3          1     3       7         0.7     0    0.60
#4          1     4       2         0.5     1    0.65
#5          1     5       2         0.8     1    0.65
#6          1     6       7         0.6     2    0.55
#7          1     7       7         0.5     2    0.55
```

---

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Chromome' and run-length-type id (`rleid`) of 'Founder', we assign (`:=`) the `mean` of "Probability" as the "Average" column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Average := mean(Probability) , .(Chromosome, grp1 = rleid(Founder))]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
This was my first question here. In the end I used the data.table option. 
`dplyr` gave me: `Error: expecting a single value`.
The data.table option overwrote my founder variable, this one was easily replaced again. So, problem solved. :)

Comment: @tboersma  I am using `dplyr_0.5.0`.  It is working with your example dataset

Comment: I am using `dplyr_0.4.3` and also having `plyr_1.8.4`. It still gives me `Error: expecting single value`. 
My data has 4 more columns, but this should not matter.